# Saleor ecommerce software build gives error 'npm ERR! missing script: build-assets'

Tags: django, npm, saleor

I was trying to setup saleor ecommerce software using the standard guide for windows (https://docs.saleor.io/docs/getting-started/installation-windows/). 
On reaching step 9,**Prepare front-end assets**, and running the command **npm run build-assets** I got the following error.

```
npm ERR! missing script: build-assets
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     build-schema
npm ERR!     build-emails

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

The complete log is pasted below:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build-assets'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v12.16.2
4 verbose stack Error: missing script: build-assets
4 verbose stack
4 verbose stack Did you mean one of these?
4 verbose stack     build-schema
4 verbose stack     build-emails
4 verbose stack     at run (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:155:19)
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:63:5
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:116:5
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:436:5
4 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:391:45)
4 verbose stack     at final (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:434:3)
4 verbose stack     at then (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:161:5)
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:382:12
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:115:16
4 verbose stack     at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:63:3)
5 verbose cwd C:\store\saleor
6 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
7 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build-assets"
8 verbose node v12.16.2
9 verbose npm  v6.14.4
10 error missing script: build-assets
10 error
10 error Did you mean one of these?
10 error     build-schema
10 error     build-emails
11 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

**This is the package.json file **

```
{
  "name": "saleor",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://github.com/mirumee/saleor.git"
  },
  "author": "Mirumee Software",
  "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/mirumee/saleor/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "http://getsaleor.com/",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "mjml": "^4.6.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build-schema": "python manage.py get_graphql_schema > saleor/graphql/schema.graphql",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build-emails",
    "build-emails": "mjml --config.beautify false -l skip \"templates/templated_email/source/*.mjml\" -o templates/templated_email/compiled"
  }
}
```

I am very new to how nodejs works. Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

Does your package.json file contain build-assets within the scripts? If not then the instructions you've been given are wrong.

Whenever you run "npm run 'script-name-here' " it would search package.json and execute the appropritate commands next to it. For example, this package.json:

```
 {
 "name": "lyrical",
 "version": "1.0.0",
"description": "My cool json file",
"main": "index.js",
 "repository": {
"type": "git",
"url": "https://github.com/user/project.git"
  },

 "scripts": {
"dev": "NOTE_SCHEDULE=localhost:2000     MONGO=localhost REDIS=localhost 
PORT=3000 node --nolazy --inspect-brk index.js",

 "prod": "NOTE_SCHEDULE=note-schedule:4000 MONGO=mongo     REDIS=redis     
 PORT=5000 node index.js"
 },

"author": "",
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
  "apollo-client": "^0.8.1",
  "apollo-server-express": "^2.9.15",
  "axios": "^0.15.3",
  "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
  "babel-loader": "^6.2.10"
 }
}
```

Take a look at the "scripts" section. If I was to run "npm run dev" I would have the following line of commands executed. I could just run the commands directly and the result would the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response, when trying to follow your guide, I saw what you were trying to tell me but sincerely speaking I don't know what will be the 'key' and the 'value' that will fix this error since I noticed that "build-emails" seems to have some kind of long value "mjml --config.beautify false -l skip \"templates/templated_email/source/*.mjml\" -o templates/templated_email/compiled"

Answer (score 0):

You haven't done anything wrong.

The problem is one of the following two options:

1. A bug for a missing script entry, `build-assets` in the Saleor project's `package.json`
2. Incorrect documentation with regards to step 9 of [their docs](https://docs.saleor.io/docs/getting-started/installation-windows/).

You should report this to Saleor.

**Edit:** I see you did report it in [issue #5616 for *npm run build-assets*](https://github.com/mirumee/saleor/issues/5616). Thanks for contributing back to the project, I hope they respond quickly.

**Edit:** There was a [response](https://github.com/mirumee/saleor-docs/issues/123#issuecomment-626554887) to your GitHub issue wherein they point to a [newer set of documentation](https://docs.saleor.io/docs/developer/installation/windows/).

Comment: @toppylawz There was a response to your GitHub issue: https://github.com/mirumee/saleor-docs/issues/123#issuecomment-626554887 wherein they point to a newer set of documentation: https://docs.saleor.io/docs/developer/installation/windows/